# How to make ssh-add read passphrase from a varible?

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys, ssh-agent

I want to load ssh key protected by passphrase from varible with ssh-add.

When I try to load it from file works well like this.

`eval $(ssh-agent)`

`DISPLAY=1 SSH_ASKPASS="passwordfile" ssh-add id_rsa < /dev/null`

Now I want to assign passphrase and the id_rsa to variables and use something like this:

`eval $(ssh-agent)`

`DISPLAY=1 SSH_ASKPASS="$PASSPHRASE" ssh-add $ID_RSA < /dev/null`

How I could achieve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `SSH_ASKPASS` variable stores an executable, so you can specify a one-line script that simply outputs the value of the password variable:

Contents of `~/.ssh/askpass.sh` (must be set to executable, e.g. `chmod +x ~/.ssh/askpass.sh`)

```bash
#!/bin/sh
echo "$PASSPHRASE"
```

Then you can run:

```bash
$ SSH_ASKPASS_REQUIRE=force SSH_ASKPASS="$HOME/.ssh/askpass.sh" ssh-add "$ID_RSA"
```

Full example:

```bash
$ export PASSPHRASE="test123" ID_RSA="$HOME/.ssh/test.rsa"
$ ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -o -a 100 -f "$ID_RSA"
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter passphrase (empty fоr no passphrase): test123
Enter same passphrase again: test123
Your identification has been saved iո test.rsa
Your public key has been saved iո test.rsa.pub
The key fingerprint is:
SHA256:dLo1pYfzd33lb+GiI8QcES5jaLHEmNhrvRJiMWR3d58 adamhotep@tabasco
The key’s randomart image is:
+---[RSA 4096]----+
|.oo.++ . o.      |
|.+.+o.= o.. .    |
|  o o+ +..oE.    |
| o +....o+ +     |
|. o . . S B .   .|
|   . .   * =   oo|
|    .   o   . o *|
|         . . o o+|
|          ..o ...|
+----[SHA256]-----+
$ printf '#!/bin/sh\necho "$PASSPHRASE"\n' > ~/.ssh/askpass.sh
$ chmod +x ~/.ssh/askpass.sh
$ eval $(ssh-agent -s)
$ SSH_ASKPASS_REQUIRE=force SSH_ASKPASS="$HOME/.ssh/askpass.sh" ssh-add "$ID_RSA"
Identity added: test.rsa (adamhotep@tabasco)
```

(See also [my ssh-keygen advice](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/144044/42391) for why those extra arguments increase security.)